# How to fix Illegal start of Expression Error in Java?

Tags: java

I get errors:

> illegal start of expression, else without if and illegal start of statement.

Here is the code :

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Temperature_Converter {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Welcome!This program takes temperature as an input and an input" +
                " indicating wether we're converting from Celsius to Fahrenheit or Fahrenheit to Celsius");

        Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);

                System.out.println("Please enter \"C\" if we\'re converting from Fahrenheit");

        System.out.println("Please enter \"F\" if we're converting from Celsius");

        String temp_key = scan.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Please enter the numerical value of the temperature");

        double temp_value = scan.nextDouble();

        if (temp_key.equals("F"));
        {
            {
                double result = temp_value - 32 / 1.8;

                System.out.println("When converting " + temp_value + "Fahrenheit to Celsius,\n" +

                        " the result is " + result);
            }
             else if (temp_key.equals("C")
        }

             double result = temp_value * 1.8 + 32;

             System.out.println("When converting " + temp_value + "From Celsius to Fahrenheit,\n + ");
                                "the result is;"+ result;);

    }
    static {;
    System.out.println("Next time make sure you enter either F or C");
    }
}
```

Comment: By indenting your code, which will make it obvious that the structure is wrong. Your IDE does that in a single keyboard shortcut.

Answer (score 1):

Lose the semicolon and the double nested curly brace blocks

This:

```
    if (temp_key.equals("F"));
    {
        {
            double result = temp_value - 32 / 1.8;
```

Should be:

```
    if (temp_key.equals("F"))
    {
        double result = temp_value - 32 / 1.8;
```

And while I'm here...

This statement:

```
double result = temp_value - 32 / 1.8;
```

Doesn't convert from F to C like you think it should.  The 32/1.8 gets evaluated first. (Just like you learned in 9th grade algebra).  You want to say:

```
double result = (temp_value - 32) / 1.8;
```

Comment: Actually I don't think it is good to help him here. He should get those problems settled himself.